# Why is LINQ expression causing two separate queries on the DB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have the following LINQ expression:

`var rawData = ( from e in _man.Details

                 where e.Id == "G00"

                 select e).ToList();`

which when I run with Profiler open I can see causes *two* separate *identical* queries.  What is the reason for this and how can this be prevented?

Comment: Could you post the query that you see?

Comment: It's very long however it's structure is `SELECT 
[Extent1].[ColumnName].....FROM (SELECT[Viewname].[COLUMNNAME]....WHERE N'GOO' = [EXTENT1].[ID]`  The reason for its length is all the columns.

Comment: What does "cause a query" mean? It should only fetch the rows once, in the ToList().

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I mean that it queries the database twice (two identical queries in Profiler) that occurs when ToList() is called once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check what is the value in EventClass column in profiler. It probably is **SQL:Batch Starting** and **SQL:Batch Completing** (or something similar). Which does not mean 2 queries, but the start and end of execution of one query.

Comment: Ah you nailed it in one, I was reading the result of profiler incorrectly.  Thank you.